# Setting default upload area for Assets

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic

Hopefully a simple answer, but at the moment, I can't figure it out.

I'm using an Assets field in a channel entry. When the client clicks on the "Add file" button, it defaults to the "Recent Uploads" smart source.

The client only has one place they can upload files to, and it's set in the channel field settings (only upload folder checked off).

Is there a way to default to the upload folder vs. the "recent uploads" area?

Comment: You'd have to find out if there's a hook you can use, I looked here but couldn't see one...http://www.ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the answer is no based on this blog post about the addition of that Recent Uploads functionality: http://pixelandtonic.com/blog/assets-2.2

> Now with Assets 2.2, **you’re always taken to the Recent Uploads** source
>   immediately after uploading files, where we can be sure that your file
>   will be visible.

This talks about being taken to Recent Uploads after upload a file which is a little different from your question, but it seems they would have made that universal and so it would also happen when clicking through from an entry.